# How to uninstall a specific version of Python installed through source files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, uninstallation

## The problem

I was looking to a GitHub repository which contained a project that requires, at least, that either Python 3.5 or **Python 3.6** is installed plus a series of specific modules that can only be used on those versions of Python 3. I have made some tests on the project but now I don't need anymore the specific version of Python installed on my PC.

### What I did

Since in my PC I have already installed Python 3.7 and 3.8, I simply navigate to the official website of Python and downloaded the [Python 3.6.13](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3613/) sources and installed it with the following commands:

```
cd <downloaded directory>
make
sudo make install
```

Since this version of Python is installed through `make` I tough I could simply remove it by going into the downloaded folder and running the command `sudo make uninstall` but when I execute this command I get the following message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'.  Stop.
```

Plus when I ran the command `python3` in the terminal it always shows up that is using the 3.6.13 version now instead of 3.8 (which is the one I'm using most of the time).

### What I want

I simply want to remove **Python 3.6.13** from my system and reuse Python 3.8 as my default version of python to use when I ran the command on the terminal

I'm using Linux Lite 5.4 (which is based from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).

Comment: Suggest : Make an another 'make install' to get an install log : `sudo make install > Install-log.txt` .... to know the files to delete. ... No uninstall in any Python version : Deleting files is the only way.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thank you for answering my question. It actually worked. Most of the files were in the `usr/local/lib` folder and a few amounts in the `usr/local/bin` . I have erased the files and when I run the command `python3` in the terminal it shows that is using python3.8. Thank you so much.